# Custom renderer on a JTextField. Is it possible ?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, renderer

I need to create component that looks like JTextField (same borders, shadows, rounded corners etc) but for displaying some graphic with text.

Is it possible to create something like renderer for a JTextField? 
Or 
Create custom component based on JPanel, but how to force it to looks same as JTextField

Another complication is that application will be running on different LAF's changed on the fly.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: why not build it? let's say by having a JPanel and putting inside it a JTExtField and a Rectangle, ...

Comment: because of borders i want to have component as similar to jtextfield as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Swing does not provide any DefaultTextFieldRenderer or TextFieldRendere interface you can build on top of.
You mention you like L&F aware rendering; thats already part of the answer: you would have to implement a UI for each L&F to render graphics into a TextField - this *may* be feasible for a selected few (lets say Windows/Mac/Metal), but hardly for *any* L&F that a user may want to use (if you leave them a choice).

Let me guess, you have the requirement to display some sort of status/validation icon with the field. Do the next best thing and display that as an icon *next* to the field, not in the TextField itself. Much less trouble :)

Comment: Yes, its some kind of status field, with a lamp and text. in the time beeing i'm using jpanel but the different borders and shades are not only annoying. I'm looking for example how to apply UI of JTextField to my custom panel. If its possible ofcourse.

Answer (score 8):

Use a [`JTextPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) or [`JEditorPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) that can handle styled text (with embedded icons).  See [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for more details.

[image: Embedded images in rich text documents]

---

### Update

> I need to create custom component that looks as JTextField in diferent Look and Feels, Using JTextPane or JEditorPane will change the borders shading and component.

Really?  This next screenshot shows all 3.  Which is which?

[image: Distinguish These]

(No cheating by looking at the code 1st.)

As to the PLAF.  Show me a PLAF in which there is any visible distinction between them.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class DistinguishThese {

    public void initGui() {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,0,2,2));

        gui.add(new JTextField(5));
        gui.add(new JScrollPane(new JEditorPane()));
        gui.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextPane()));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                DistinguishThese dt = new DistinguishThese();
                dt.initGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats not what I'm trying to do, as I wrote  I need to create custom component that looks as JTextField in diferent Look and Feels, Using  JTextPane or JEditorPane will change the borders shading and component.

Comment: *"as I wrote"*  Yes, I remember from when I read it.  :(  Check the update and 'show me the PLAF'.  BTW - a `JTextField` with an image does not look like a `JTextField`, so it seems odd that you are concerned to get the borders and BG color 'pixel perfect'.

Comment: "Really? This next screenshot shows all 3. Which is which?" In other Look and Feel Yes

Comment: *"In other Look and Feel Yes"*  ***Name it!***  Give the fully qualified class-name of this PLAF that makes them look different.  For pity's sake, I cannot read you mind, so **be specific.**