# Can you insert a component instead of a character in a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcomponent

Is it possible for me to insert a component (JComponent) instead of a letter in at a certain index in a JTextField?

For example, my textfield contents would be ABD{my painted component}EDF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896310/custom-renderer-on-a-jtextfield-is-it-possible

Comment: please what's is `my painted component` which type of

Comment: no, it's not possible unless you change `JTextField` significantly.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to get text to turn into 'tags' when you hit enter so they are enclosed in rounded rectangles - like when you add tags to a stack overflow question (or add tags to a note in evernote).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use a `JTextPane`. It supports an `insertComponent(...)` method.